# XCode 4.6.3 - Adding and loading another screen in Single View project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am new to iOS development. I created a single view type iOS project in xcode 4.6.3 and I have the following header, implementation and xib files already added:-

myViewController.h ; myViewController.m ; myViewController.xib

The app runs fine and myViewController.xib loads alright. It contains a button (with a click handler in .m file already linked and executing) but I want to write some code in the click handler that could load another screen.

My app has only two screens. One was already set up while project creation but I have seen more than one ways to add another separate screen in tutorials. I am not sure if they apply to single view type project. My question is:-

1. Do I just create a new secondView.xib file and my click event in myViewController.m will load the secondView.xib in the window thorough some code? Please let me know the code if so.
2. Or should I go to File->New->Cocoa Touch and follow the whole wizard that adds new .h, .m and .xib file to the project. I have done this already but again, I don't know the code to put in my button click handler method which could dismiss the first screen and take the user to second screen.

I think I shouldn't use NavigationController since my app doesn't have any navigation header stuff. Hope I have asked the question rightly.

Many thanks

Comment: Side note: You should try to use at least Xcode 6.1. Using really out-of-date tools is only going to cause problems such as not being able to use modern devices or submit an app to Apple.

Comment: Another side note: switch to Swift. I've pointed you to Objective-C resources but it's a dangerous language, esp. for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is another complete triad of files (*SecondViewController.h*, *SecondViewController.m*, *SecondViewController.xib*), and in your button code instantiate SecondViewController and call `presentViewController...`.

Comment: Here's the relevant section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller

Comment: And here's an actual downloadable code example that does exactly this: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch06p264presentedViewController